# Display problems datagrid

Tags: wpf

I am faced with a problem: If the column header has a point in its name it does not display the value of the cells in this column.

How can I fix this without changing the name of the column?

```
var ds = new DataSet();
            var dataPylons = new DataTable();
            ds.Tables.Add(dataPylons);

foreach (var i in pylonItem)
            {
                cl = new DataColumn(i.Code + "\n" + i.Sheme, typeof(string));
                dataPylons.Columns.Add(cl);
            }

// In the cycle fill cell 
dataPylons.Rows[i][j] =...;
...
DataGridPylons.ItemsSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
```

Example error:
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3wJRn2hp50hTm9uX2FkRUg1dTQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I fully discourage the use of `System.Data` classes in WPF client-side. Create a proper data model instead.

Comment: how do I correctly generate the contents of the table?

Answer (score 0):

Datagrid columns follow the same standard as SQL column naming standards as found here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175874.aspx

You will need to stick to that.